# Find the value of $\lim_{ z \to \infty}|e^{-z}| =0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

> Is $\lim_{ z \to \infty}|e^{-z}| =0?$

Then we know that $|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. We know that $|z| \to \infty$ implies that either $x \to \infty$ or $y \to \infty$ or $x$ and $y$ both tend to $\infty$.

Case1: If $x \to \infty$ then we know that $e^{-z} = \frac{1}{e^{x}(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))}$. Now $\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$ are both bounded functions.

Then $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))}=0$.

I am stuck with the other two cases. Is this even true?

Comment: Is $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^x = 0$? Is $\lim_{y \to \infty} e^{iy} = 0$?

Comment: **Hint :** $|e^{-z}| = e^{-\mathrm{Re}(z)}$.

Comment: You're missing the $x \to - \infty$ case in your enumeration of the cases above.  Might want to think about what happens in that case.

Comment: Do you mean |z|→∞?

Comment: Yes @RamanujanXV

Comment: @TheSilverDoe can you explain the inequality?

Comment: @ThirstForMaths This is an equality and not an inequality. Just write $z=x+iy$ with $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ and use the fact that $|e^{iy}|=1$.

Comment: So $|e^{-z}|=\frac{1}{e^x}$.Then $|e^{-z}|$ converges to $0$ when $ x \to +\infty$ or if $x \to - \infty$ if $x$ doesn't tend to $\infty$ we see that $e^{-z}$ doesnt converge to $0$.

Comment: You may learn about this in the future.  The function $e^{-z}$ has an **essential singularity** at $z=\infty$, so it takes all complex values (with possibly one exception) in every neighborhood of $\infty$.  In particular, $$\liminf_{ z \to \infty}|e^{-z}| =0,\quad \limsup_{ z \to \infty}|e^{-z}| =0$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$.

Then $|z|\to\infty$ when either $|x|\to\infty$ or $|y|\to\infty$ or both . $x\to\infty$ does not encompass all cases. For the absolute value to go to infinity , either the real part or the imaginary part or both need to be unbounded that's all.

Then:-

$e^{-x-iy}=e^{-x}e^{-iy}$

So $|e^{-x-iy}|=|e^{-x}||e^{-iy}|=e^{-x} $ as $|e^{-iy}|=1$.

So Now take a sequence $z_{n}=n+0i$ . Then $|e^{z_{n}}|=e^{-n}\,,\forall n$.

So for this sequence $\lim_{n\to\infty}|e^{z_{n}}|=0$.

But take $z_{n}=-n+0i$.

Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}|e^{z_{n}}|=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{n}=\infty$.

Now take $z_{n}=0+ni$ .

Then $|e^{z_{n}}|=e^{-0}=1$ . So the limit is $1$.

Now do you see the argument?. In all these cases $|z_{n}|\to \infty$. The point is that for different sequences you get different limits. Hence $\lim_{|z|\to\infty}|e^{-z}|$ does not exist.